# Magento 2 - Load products invisible individually using GraphQL

Tags: magento, graphql, magento2

we have a Magento 2 installation and we are building a new frontend using GraphQL. We need to load some information for products that are not visibile individually. They are simple products part of a configurable products. We don't want to make them visible in listing or search but there are places where we have to load a specific variant and show some infos.

Is there a way to allow GraphQL queries to return those products ? we are trying to load them using SKU.

Magento version 2.3.4

Thanks

Comment: if parts of product then they should be queried as its children, by prop/relation

Comment: Yes i know that but I have configurable products with many many simple products associated and I don't want to load all of them and filter the list on the client. It tooks too much time. I just need to load the details of a single simple product